# Variable and if input

Tags: jquery

What is wrong with this code? I declare a variable, then i say if it is 0 hide, if it is 1 animate. Then, when you click on it, the variable become 1 and so it animate. The code hides #slickbox11, but, when i click on it, it doesn't "animate" itself and the scroll.

```
   var slickbox11 = 0

    //slickbox11//
    $(document).ready(function() {
    if (slickbox11 == 0){
    $('#slickbox11').hide();    
    }
    })

    $(document).ready(function() {
    if (slickbox11 == 1){
    $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: 135}, 300);
    $('#slickbox11').animate({ opacity: '1', height: '1' }, 300 );
    }
    })


    $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#slick-toggle11').click(function() {
    slickbox11 = 1;
    })
    })
```

Comment: why do you have each statement in its own document ready?

Comment: Why all the document.ready() functions?  are these all in the same js file or HTML file?

Comment: You're not telling it to animate, you're only changing the value of a variable on the click event.

Comment: You forgot a `;` after the variable declaration on line one. Should be `var slickbox11 = 0;`

Answer (score 1):

Animate is not rerunning every time you click.  it's not part of your click handler.  You could check the state of the variable in the click handler and toggle the state of slickbox11 appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

$(document).ready only gets executed once when all the DOMs are loaded so you'll have to bind the animation to the click event itself.

You should probably use toggleClass like:

```
$('#slick-toggle11').click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('animate');
    if ($(this).hasClass('animate')) 
       //animate
    else
       //animate some other way
})
```

Answer (score 0):

First off, you only should have 1 `$(document).ready...`.

To make it work:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#slick-toggle11').click(function() {
        $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: 135}, 300);
        $('#slickbox11').animate({ opacity: '1', height: '1' }, 300 );
    });
});
```

Javascript is event driven, all those `$(document).ready...` only get fired once. So setting the variable to 1 is doing just that, setting a variable. You need to have the action you want to happen (animate, scroll), tied to an event (click).

Answer (score 0):

because the if statements are evaluated in the ready method and then forgotten.  the $(document).ready function is not run every time a variable changes but when the document is *ready*.  Therefore, when you click the element, $(document).ready has already run a long time ago and if you want to call another method you have to do it in the click event.

```
var slickbox11 = 0

$(document).ready(function() {
    run();
    $('#slick-toggle11').click(function() {
      slickbox11 = 1;
      run();
    })
})

function run() {
  if (slickbox11 == 1){
    $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: 135}, 300);
    $('#slickbox11').animate({ opacity: '1', height: '1' }, 300 );
  } else if (slickbox11 == 0){
    $('#slickbox11').hide();    
  }
}
```

Comment: What you've written doesn't do any toggling of the display. After the first click it'll never hit the condition to hide.

Comment: @CAbbott that wasn't even coded in by the poster nor specified as a requirement... where did you get toggle out of it?  According to the poster's requirements, it's supposed to animate when clicked, not toggle animate.